# Weil Restriction and Distinguished Opens

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

I have a pair of related questions about Weil Restriction. Let $E/F$ be a field extension, and let $A$ be an $E-$algebra. Assume that all relevant restrictions of scalars exist. We have a norm map $n: A \rightarrow RA$. I wish to show that for $f \in A$ we have $R(A_f) \simeq (RA)_{n(f)}$ (this is problem 11.4.7(6) in Springer's Linear Algebraic Groups).

Using functoriality, given the map $A \rightarrow A_f$, we have an induced map $RA \rightarrow R(A_f)$ and since $n(f) \in RA$ is mapped to something invertible in $R(A_f)$, by universal properties, the morphism $RA \rightarrow R(A_f)$ factors through $(RA)_{n(f)} \rightarrow R(A_f)$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed here.

A more unified perspective here is probably given by the functors of points and thinking relatively. So here, working over a base scheme $S' \rightarrow S$, for an $S$-scheme $Y$ and an $S'$-scheme $X$ we have

$Hom_{S'}(Y \times_S S', X)=Hom_S(Y, \Pi_{S'/S}X).$

Moreover in this setting, we know that taking restrictions of scalars commutes with base change. So my question is; what is the schematic formulation of the above question? Let $X=Spec(A)$ be an $S'$ scheme. Then my impression is that the base change diagram for localization would be $Spec(A_f) \times_{S'} Spec(A)$.

Then by an easy argument, we have

$\Pi_{S'/S}(Spec(A_f) \times_{S'} Spec(A)) \simeq \Pi(Spec(A_f)) \times_{\Pi(S')} \Pi(Spec(A))$.

Though it seems close, I cannot quite figure out if this is the correct analogue of the statement above. Moreover here it seems I don't even introduce the norm map at all, or use any universal properties about localization, so I am unsure of myself.

Please let me know if you have any comments or if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Hey Marc. I worry that my answer below maybe doesn't really answer what you're asking. If not, please let me know and I'll try to modify it. By the way, I hope you don't mind me remarking, but I think Milne's recent book on algebraic groups is clearer than Springer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Res}{\mathsf{Res}}$ $\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$$\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$

I'd like to tell you a way to think about this that I think is instructive. I hope you feel similarly even though, most likely, it's outside the purview of what Springer is actually discussing.

---

For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $E/F$ is Galois and let me denote by $\Gamma$ the group $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ and we denote a general element of $\Gamma$ by $\sigma$ or $\tau$.

Let us begin by defining for all $\sigma$ in $\Gamma$ the $E$-algebra

$$A^\sigma:= A\otimes_{E,\sigma}E$$

where this notation means that we're taking the tensor product of $E$-algebras where $E\to A$ is the structure map and $E\to E$ is the map given by $\sigma$. We consider this an $E$-algebra by defining $e(a\otimes b):=a\otimes (eb)$.

Let us note that we have a map of $F$-algebras

$$\sigma:A\to A^\sigma:a\mapsto a\otimes 1$$

Note though that this map is not $E$-linear. In fact,

$$\sigma(ea)=(ea)\otimes 1 = a\otimes \sigma(e)=\sigma(e)(a\otimes 1)$$

so $\sigma:A\to A^\sigma$ is $\sigma$-linear.

We now consider the $E$-algebra

$$A^{\otimes \Gamma}:=\bigotimes_{\sigma\in\Gamma_F}A^\sigma$$

where the tensor product on the right hand side is a tensor product of $E$-algebras. We shall denote a general simple tensor in $A^{\otimes\Gamma}$ by $\displaystyle \bigotimes a_\sigma$ (i.e. the $\sigma^\text{th}$-coordinate in the simple tensor is $a_\sigma$). Note that $A^{\otimes\Gamma}$ carries a natural $\Gamma$-action by permuting the coordinates or, more explicitly,

$$\tau\left(\bigotimes a_\sigma\right)=\bigotimes b_\sigma,\qquad b_{\tau\sigma}=a_\sigma$$

Note that the action of $\Gamma$ is not $E$ linear, but is $F$-linear.

Let us now consider the $F$-algebra $(A^{\otimes \Gamma})^{\Gamma}$--the $\Gamma$-fixed points of $A^{\otimes \Gamma}$. We have an obvious inclusion of $F$-algebras

$$\iota:(A^{\otimes\Gamma})^{\Gamma}\hookrightarrow A^{\otimes \Gamma}$$

Less obviously is the fact that the induced map of $E$-algebras

$$(A^{\otimes\Gamma})^{\Gamma}\otimes_F E\to A^{\otimes\Gamma}:x\otimes e\mapsto ex$$

is an isomorphism of $E$-algebras. In fact, it's actually an isomorphism of $E$-algebras with an action of $\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ acts on the source by its action on $E$!

Why is $A^{\otimes\Gamma}$ or $(A^{\otimes{\Gamma}})^{\Gamma}$-important? Well, note that for any $F$-algebra $R$ the obvious map

$$\Hom_F\left((A^{\otimes \Gamma})^\Gamma,R\right)\to \Hom_E\left ((A^{\otimes \Gamma})^\Gamma\otimes_F E,R\otimes_F E\right)^{\Gamma}$$

is a bijection where the $\Gamma$ action on

$$\Hom_E\left ((A^{\otimes \Gamma})^\Gamma\otimes_F E,R\otimes_F E\right)$$

takes a homomorphism $\alpha$ to $\sigma\circ \alpha\circ \sigma^{-1}$ where $\sigma^{-1}$ is acting on $(A^{\otimes \Gamma})^\Gamma\otimes_F E$ by its action on $E$ and the action of $\sigma$ is on $R\otimes_F E$ also acting by $E$.

But, we've already noted that we have an isomorphism

$$(A^{\otimes\Gamma})^{\Gamma}\otimes_F E\to A^{\otimes\Gamma}:x\otimes e\mapsto ex$$

of $E$-algebras with $\Gamma$-action. Thus, we see that

$$\Hom_E\left ((A^{\otimes \Gamma})^\Gamma\otimes_F E,R\otimes_F E\right)^{\Gamma}=\Hom_E\left (A^{\otimes\Gamma},R\otimes_F E\right)^{\Gamma}$$

but what is a $\Gamma$-equivariant map of $E$-algebras $A^{\otimes \Gamma}\to R\otimes_F E$? Well, by the definition of tensor product over $E$, its a collection of maps of $E$-algebras

$$f_\sigma:A^\sigma\to R\otimes_F E$$

where we abbreviate $f_{\mathrm{id}}$ to $f$ such that for any collection $a_\sigma\in A^\sigma$ you have

$$f_\sigma(a_\sigma)=\sigma(f(a))$$

In other words, you see that such data is an entirely determined by $f$.

In other words, summing everything up, there is a natural series of bijections

$$\begin{align}\Hom_F\left((A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma,R\right) &= \Hom_E\left((A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma\otimes_F E,R\otimes_F E\right)^\Gamma\\ &= \Hom_E(A^{\otimes\Gamma},R\otimes_F E)^\Gamma\\ &= \Hom_E(A,R\otimes_F E)\end{align}$$

or, in other words, we have shown that

$$\Res_{E/F}\Spec(A)=\Spec\left((A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma\right)$$

More explicitly we have a bijection

$$J:\Hom_F\left((A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma,R\right)\xrightarrow{\approx}\Hom_E(A,R\otimes_F E)$$

given by taking $f$ to $(f\otimes 1)\mid_A$.

---

Now, what does this have to do with the norm map?Note we have a multiplicative map

$$N:A\to A^{\otimes \Gamma}:a\mapsto \bigotimes \sigma(a)$$

which we call the *norm* map. Note that this map is not additive but does have image in $(A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma$.

Thus, if $a\in A$ then $N(a)\in (A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma$. Given our above discussion it's now easy to verify that

$$\Res_{E/F}(D(a))=D(N(a))$$

Indeed, what is a map of $F$-schemes

$$\Spec(R)\to D(N(a))$$

but a map of $F$-algebras

$$(A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma\to R$$

such that $N(a)$ maps to a unit. What is a map of $E$-schemes

$$\Spec(R\otimes_F E)\to\Spec(A)$$

but a map of $E$-algebras

$$A\to R\otimes_F E$$

Note then that under our above bijection

$$\Hom_F\left((A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma,R\right)\xrightarrow{\approx}\Hom_E(A,R\otimes_F E)$$

one sees that

$$f(N(a))=J(f)(a)$$

and so $f(N(a))$ is a unit iff $J(f)(a)$ is. This is precisely what we want.

---

Let me say one last word on what the relationship is between the norm map

$$N:A\to (A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma$$

and more familiar versions of the norm map. Namely, let us suppose that there is some $F$-algebra $B$ such that $A=B\otimes_F E$. Then, we note that we have an isomorphism of $E$-algebras

$$A^\sigma=B\otimes_F E\otimes_{E,\sigma}E\to A=B\otimes_F E:(b\otimes e_1)\otimes e_2\mapsto b\sigma(e_1)e_2$$

With this, one can show that there is an isomorphism of $E$-algebras

$$A^{\otimes \Gamma}\cong B\otimes_E E^{\otimes\Gamma}\cong A\otimes_E (E^{|\Gamma|})\cong B^{|\Gamma|}$$

Moreover, it's not hard to check then that the natural map

$$B\to (A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma$$

is an isomorphism. Thus, we see that the norm map is a map

$$N:B\otimes_F E=A\to (A^{\otimes\Gamma})^\Gamma=B$$

Now, let $x\in B\otimes_F E$ act on the left of $B\otimes_F E$ by left multiplication denote this by $\ell_x$. Since $B\otimes_F E$ is a free $B$-module of finite rank, one can consider $\det(\ell_x)\in B$. Then, one has , under the above identifications, that $N(x)=\det(\ell_x)$.

Comment: Alex, this is a great answer, since it gives me a very concrete way to approach these problems. I've accepted it. The one further thing that I might ask  is about the schematic stuff. For instance, I imagine that this is a pretty important basic fact. However, when I look in the appendices of Oesterle or Pseudoreductive Groups, I don't see this basic fact, but rather just the base change property. Oesterle mentions that localizations are examples of base changes, so a final question would be: is the base change above the correct one for expressing this fact?

Comment: @MarcBesson Hey Marc. Funny enough, I'm not really sure this is an important fact. In fact, I had never even heard of it before your asked this question and I use Weil restriction a lot in my working life. Of course, the reason for this is, as you'd expect, one rarely thinks about the Weil restriction as a locally ringed spaces thinking about it almost entirely functorially. Now, as to your question. By commuting with base change you mean something like Proposition A.5.2(3) of CGP? I'm not really sure how to apply this here. Namely, do you want to cleverly choose the $X_i'$ so that

Comment: the base change there just magically reads $\mathsf{Res}_{E/}(D(a))=D(N(a))$? I just don't think that's really possible for several reasons. FIrst how do you get $D(f)$? You seem to think perhaps that $D(a)=D(a)\times_{\text{Spec}(F)}X$, but this is not true (e.g. just think about the case when $D(a)=X$!). It is true that $D(fa=D(a)\times_X X$ but I don't think that's of particular help since the cited result in CGP's appendix would just say that $\mathsf{Res}_{E/F}(D(a))=\mathsf{Res}_{E/F}(D(a))\times_{\mathsf{Res}_{E/F}(X)}\mathsf{Res}_{E/F}(X)$ which is not particularly useful.

Comment: Also, as you yourself pointed out, I'm not sure how you're going ot make the norm show up by this abstract base change approach. There might be a way of phrasing everything I wrote above in a purely non-ring theoretic way (e.g. what I described above is just Galois descent, which is just etale descent--but you can do it for fppf descent if you don't want to assume that $E/F$ is separable--see Section 4.4 of Bjorn Poonen's book on rational points for a discussion in this vein), but that's about it. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Alex, thank you so much, this has been a very valuable discussion for me! You're certainly right that I don't have a base change which "looks like" localization, but I probably shouldn't pursue that too far in any case.